# epmd.service: Job epmd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, epmd

greeting everyone,
I am configuring a compute node (nova) with OpenStack.
When I try to enable the node I get multiple error with epmd , Erlang port mapper and mcelog.
I've searched online and tried some solutions but not luck, plus the info on some of the errors is low.
I would appreciate if some one can walk me through this issue so I understand what was done wrong and what to do to fix it.
Bellow is the log ext and error I get.

[image]

```
The unit fprintd.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Dec 21 22:29:24 firasc systemd[1]: Failed to create listening socket: Address already in use
Dec 21 22:29:24 firasc systemd[1]: epmd.socket: Failed to listen on sockets: Address already in use
Dec 21 22:29:24 firasc systemd[1]: epmd.socket: Failed with result 'resources'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- The unit epmd.socket has entered the 'failed' state with result 'resources'.
Dec 21 22:29:24 firasc systemd[1]: Failed to listen on Erlang Port Mapper Daemon Activation Socket.
-- Subject: Unit epmd.socket has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit epmd.socket has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dec 21 22:29:24 firasc systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Erlang Port Mapper Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit epmd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit epmd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Dec 21 22:29:24 firasc systemd[1]: epmd.service: Job epmd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Dec 21 22:30:36 firasc systemd[1]: Reloading.
Dec 21 22:30:36 firasc systemd[1]: 
Dec 21 22:30:36 firasc systemd[1]: epmd@0.0.0.0.socket: Unit has no Listen setting (ListenStream=, ListenDatagram=, ListenFIFO=, ...). Refusing.
```

Comment: Which guide did you follow to install? How does your rabbitmq and epmd config look like?

Comment: ive followed this site with every step  : https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_Stream_8&p=openstack_wallaby&f=2

Comment: You'll need to configure epmd, possibly in `/etc/sysconfig/erlang` and it should map your rabbitmq settings. The guide does not cover that, I've had to figure this out from time to time what exactly the system requires. For example, the file could look like this:

`EPMD_ADDRESSES="127.0.0.1"
EPMD_PORT="4369"`